# The filter "empty" does not exist at Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension, symfony-2.7

I'm migrating an app from Symfony 2.0.15 to Symfony 2.7.0-BETA1 and I'm getting this error:

> The filter "empty" does not exist in PDOneBundle::pdone.html.twig at line 1

This is the code for `Extension\PDOneTwigExtension`:

```
class PDOneTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'var_dump'   => new \Twig_Filter_Function('var_dump'),
            'empty'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'is_empty'),
            'isset'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'is_set'),
            'isnull'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'is_null'),
            'ucfirst'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'uc_first'),
            'ucwords'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'uc_words'),
            'count'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'co_unt'),
            'sizeof'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'size_of'),
            'concat'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'concat'),
            'in_array'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'inarray'),
            'array'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'array_'),
            'add_to_array'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'add_to_array'),
            'replace'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'replace'),
            'htmlentitydecode'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'htmlentitydecode'),
        );
    }

    public function is_empty($sentence)
    {
        return empty($sentence);
    }

    // others methods goes here

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pdone_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

And this is the call at `pdone.html.twig`:

```
{% if form_action|empty == true or form_action|isnull == true or form_action|isset == false %} {% set form_action = '' %} {% endif %}
```

What I'm missing here? Where is the error?

**UPDATE**

I've made the following changes at my code:

```
// Changes for use Twig_SimpleFilter() insted of Twig_Filter_Method()
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        'var_dump'   => new \Twig_Filter_Function('var_dump'),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('empty', array($this, 'is_empty')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('isset', array($this, 'is_set')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('isnull', array($this, 'is_null')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('ucfirst', array($this, 'uc_first')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('ucwords', array($this, 'uc_words')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('count', array($this, 'co_unt')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('sizeof', array($this, 'size_of')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('concat', array($this, 'concat')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('in_array', array($this, 'inarray')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('array', array($this, 'array_')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('add_to_array', array($this, 'add_to_array')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('replace', array($this, 'replace')),
        new Twig_SimpleFilter('htmlentitydecode', array($this, 'htmlentitydecode'))
    );
}
```

Loads extension in `services.yml`:

```
services:
    pdone.twig.extension:
        class: GroupDCA\PDOneBundle\Extension\PDOneTwigExtension
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

But still getting the same issue, any other idea? A clue? Something else I can try?

**Update 2**

I got the issue fixed but I'm getting this:

> Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you
>   can use "null !== expression" instead)

I don't know how to fix this one. I take a look to the stacktrace but I got only this:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
    at n/a
        in /var/www/html//reptooln_admin/app/cache/dev/twig/68/7f/63589dd3687cb849dd68e6b6c10aa99eda1d82f95a5f3ac52a864d200499.php line 39
```

What could be wrong? Can any give me some help on this one?

Comment: Your `Twig_extension` is missing the required `getName` function. You also need to add an instance of the `class` to twig : `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new PDOneTwigExtension ());` [reference](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-extensions). Another note, the test `empty` is standard in `twig`. See ghanbari answer on how to use `empty` as test

Comment: I don't understand how most of your filters make writing your templates easier. Personally I'd think `{% if form_action is empty %}` is way simpler than `{% if form_action|empty == true %}`.. It would make sense if you did `{% if form_action|empty %}` but I'm imagining Twig parsing errors if you did `{% if !form_action|empty %}`.

Comment: @DarkBee the method exists in the class, I did not show before because  I believe it was not important for the error that I have but anyway I have added to the main post. Where I should add the instance of the `class` to `Twig`? I mean docs says this: `You can register an extension by using the addExtension() method on your main Environment object` but where is that? I am confused, can you give me an advice?

Comment: @DarkBee and for your last doubt remember this is not my code perhaps when the application was build that filters doesn't exist

Comment: @sjagr again, this is not developed by me I am just trying to upgrade the app and will spent some time trying to get the app working with new Symfony release

Comment: If you are using symphony you can register the extension as a [service]( http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: @DarkBee I've registered as extension

Comment: And its working now?

Comment: @DarkBee no, I am still getting the same issue :-\ it's the `getFilters` definition right?

Comment: @ReynierPM I just noticed your not using `Twig_SimpleFilter`. Try it like this : [link](http://pastebin.com/kHAQmyBR)

Comment: @DarkBee still not working, see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know your answer, but twig have standard function that you can use them, see this example:

```
{% if form_action is empty or form_action is null or form_action is not defined %}
    {% set form_action = '' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: While this is correct and default in `twig`, it does not answer OP's question as you are using the `test` empty rather than OP's `filter` empty :-)